# type 'UploadFileInfo' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

[Image Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9nSW.png)

I am trying to upload a file in flutter using HTTP package with some parameters and some headers. But it's occurring a problem in UploadFileInfo. this is my actual exception:

> " type 'UploadFileInfo' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast "

Comment: instead of image... please put your code and full exception as text. So that we could help better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ContentType` you're using

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

is used for encoded strings like:

```
field1=value1&field2=value2
```

For usage with `FormData` the `ContentType` you need should be

```
multipart/form-data
```

as a content type.

But, as far as I know Dio is smart enough to understand it, so you could try omitting the `ContentType` header too!